# Creating multiple temporary aliases

Tags: alias

I am not a root user & I don't have access to the global alias file which has all the aliases created, but I want to create some aliases which remain active only for the session I am logged in. 
I use the command `alias x='cd /parent/child'` to create an alias which will enable me to just type `x` on the console & I change dir to /Parent/Child .

However, I want to create multiple aliases & I don't want to type each alias I create every time.

I tried putting all the alias='do this' lines in a file (gave it 777 permission) hoping that on running the file all these aliases would be created every time I login. But that didn't happen.

ex :

```
alias x='cd /parent/child'
alias y='cd /a/b/c'
alias z='tail -0f some.log'
```

I also tried this in the file but in vain:

```
alias x='cd /parent/child';alias y='cd /a/b/c';alias z='tail -0f some.log'
```

None of the alias names I tried were already present in the global alias. (I typed alias & saw the output on the screen).

Comment: You can put all your aliases in `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @Web Nash: But if you want to pass different arguments to different commands then this won't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

generate all you session alias in a file, for instance alias.txt

```
alias x='cd /parent/child'
alias y='cd /a/b/c'
alias z='tail -0f some.log'
```

then use

```
 . ./alias.txt
```

You sould have all you alias in alias list, for this single session.

Edit:

Be sure to use

```
. ./alias.txt
```

not

```
./alias.txt
```

In former case, content is read 'as if typed', while the latter case will define alias in a shell that will exit.

Comment: I did a similar thing initially before I posted this question. Instead of a text file I just put these lines in a file without any extension & that didn't work. But even when I tried it with a .txt extension it didnt work

Comment: That worked Perfectly. Thank You so much. 
I didn't understand the difference between using these three forms 

1) alias.txt
2) ./alias.txt
3) . ./alias.txt

Comment: form 1) and 2) are equivalent if . is in your $PATH. thay will baiscally call a new shell, run the command. In most case this is OK, however if you want alias or function, definition will dissapear when shell exit.